# ROS driver for SICK NAV350?

Tags: ros, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people,

Is there any ROS driver/node/wrapper available for the [SICK NAV350](http://www.sick.com/group/EN/home/products/product_news/laser_measurement_systems/Pages/NAV350_guidance_sensor.aspx)? I have been searching but didn't find any.

Thank you very much in advance for any info.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182215/ros-driver-for-sick-nav350?/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A colleague of mine made a NAV driver+ROS wrapper recently, based on the sicktoolbox code. It's available here:

[sicktoolbox fork](https://github.com/larics/sicktoolbox)

[sicktoolbox_wrapper fork](https://github.com/larics/sicktoolbox_wrapper)

The code needs some tyding up and there are a several hardcoded things, but we're currently using it on a project and it works :)

---

Originally posted by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) with karma: 446 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-02**:
Much appreciated, thanks! I'll try to help tiding the code and remove hardcoded things. Every time you hardcode a parameter, God kills a kitten ;)

**Comment by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on 2018-06-12**:
Hello there, this driver works great on an x86 platform, but does not seem to work on my arm platform.
can this be modified to work with the arm series of sbc's?

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2018-10-28**:
We are not using the NAV with ARM SBCs, so I can't provide any specific information at the moment. I suggest you open a new question and provide some more details about the errors you are encountering. That way someone more knowledgeable about ARM platforms might be able to help you.